# HTML Canvas horizontal flip only works every second click

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas element with a photo loaded on it. When clicking a link, the following is performed:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(-1,1);
ctx.drawImage(canvas, canvas.width * -1, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

This works as expected (the image is flipped horizontally) on the first click, the third click, the fifth click, etc. On the second click, the fourth click, the sixth click, etc, nothing happens.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work for every click?

Comment: Might be an idea to pop the whole script in there. Could be the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is because you're not restoring the canvas scale to 1,1 after you draw the image, so basically the first time the event is called your canvas scale is gonna be turned into -1,1 the next time it's gonna be 1,1 but you need it to be always -1,1. That's because you're drawing the image directly from the canvas and not from an image element thus, you gonna need to flip it every time.

Try using `ctx.save()` before the scaling and `ctx.restore()` after drawing the image. Or calling `ctx.scale(-1, 1)` again after drawing the image. Or you could just do the scaling outside the event (but after you've drawn the image to the canvas the first time) if your canvas is only used for this.

Answer (score 1):

This here works for every click:

http://jsfiddle.net/4kcjn/2/

Ask yourself, what is different between it and yours?

It could be image-load related. Try yours without an image. Does it still have the same problem?

Comment: Adding the save/restore solved the issue. I'm not sure why but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.